# javascript + mocha: probably a closure issue with functions declared inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

To learn javascript, I implement and test classic algorithms with it.

Here is my attempt at implementing binary search and tests for it:

```
var assert = require('assert')

function binsearch (xs, v) {
  if (xs === undefined || xs.length === 0) { return null }

  var lo = 0
  var hi = xs.length - 1

  while (lo <= hi) {
    var i = (lo + hi) / 2 | 0

    if (xs[i] === v) {
      return i
    } else if (v < xs[i]) {
      hi = i - 1
    } else if (v > xs[i]) {
      lo = i + 1
    }
  }

  return null
}

var check_bsearch = function (bsearch, xs, x, i) {
  it(bsearch.name + ' [' + xs + '] ' + x + ' ' + i, function () {
    assert.equal(bsearch(xs, x), i)
  })
}

describe('Test binsearch', function () {
  describe('on a sorted array', function() {
    var xs = []

    for (var i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
      xs[i] = 2 * i

      for (var j = 0; j <= i; ++j) {
        check_bsearch(binsearch, xs, 2 * j, j)
        check_bsearch(binsearch, xs, 2 * j + 1, null)

        check_bsearch(binsearch, xs, -1, null)
        check_bsearch(binsearch, xs, -2, null)

        check_bsearch(binsearch, xs, 2 * i + 1, null)
        check_bsearch(binsearch, xs, 2 * i + 2, null)
      }
    }
  })
})
```

In order to reproduce what I am about to say, copy the code above into some `bsearch.js` file, install `mocha.js` with something like `sudo npm install -g mocha` and finally run the file: `mocha bsearch.js`

One test should be failing: the one with `xs = [0], x = 2` and expected result of `null`. If you recreate this test separately though, it will pass.

I am suspecting that this is a closure issue. You might have noticed that I am already using a helper function `check_bsearch` to get the expected closure environment. However, I am clearly missing something. How do I fix the tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are passed by reference. What happens is that as you loop you modify the `xs` array you pass to your functions, and by the time the tests actually run, they all get the same value. You should copy the array so that each test gets a snapshot of its value at the time it was called. It can be as simple as:

```
var check_bsearch = function (bsearch, xs, x, i) {
    xs = xs.slice(); // Make a private copy of xs.
```